# Spring: How to use @RequestBody after reading inputStream

Tags: java, spring, http, rest, inputstream

I'm having the issue described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5806724/springs-requestbody-providing-empty-string-on-post) but it's not clear to me how to address it.

The issue is that I have an AuthenticationProvider which has to read the body of the request. When my controller method wants to use that data via @RequestMapping, however, it's empty because the Provider has already read the inputStream.

Is there a way to obtain an inputReader from Request which supports mark/reset so my provider can simply roll the stream back to it's initial state after it does the authentication? It seems crazy that the default behavior of the filter is destructive modification of the request object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Provider should be triggered only in specific cases, so it shouldn't affect your whole application. But if you need the body in the requests handled by the provider, then you still have a workaround:

1. implement a servlet `Filter`
2. wrap the request
3. in the wrapper cache the request body, and then override the `getInputStream()` method to return a `ByteArrayInputStream` with the cached request body. That way it can be read muiltiple times.

spring's `AbstractRequestLoggingFilter` does something similar and has an example wrapper, you can check it.

Comment: That sounds likely; just to shore up my understanding, "wrap the request" means extend ServletRequest and pass that on when I call chain.doFilter(request, response).
The Provider is indeed only triggered in specific cases, but of course, the case where it is triggered is the one where I need both the body in the provider and the handler method. Anyhow, thanks, and I'll accept the answer as soon as I get this running.

Comment: yes, there's `HttpServletRequestWrapper` that helps you - you extend it, instantiate it, passing the original request, and it delegates all methods, except the overridden ones