# How to access plain JSON body in Spring REST controller?

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, controller

Having the following code:

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/greeting", method = POST, consumes = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public String greetingJson(@RequestBody String json) {
    System.out.println("json = " + json); // TODO json is null... how to retrieve plain json body?
    return "Hello World!";
}
```

The String `json` argument is always `null` despite JSON being sent in the body.

**Note** that I don't want automatic type conversion, I just want the plain JSON result.

This for example works:

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/greeting", method = POST, consumes = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public String greetingJson(@RequestBody User user) {
    return String.format("Hello %s!", user);
}
```

Probably I can use the use the `ServletRequest` or `InputStream` as argument to retrieve the actual body, but I wonder if there is an easier way?

Comment: `String jsonBody = IOUtils.toString( request.getInputStream());` one-liner with Apache if you need it done quickly. [And similar question.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5806724/springs-requestbody-providing-empty-string-on-post)

Comment: This will probably indeed work, however I would like to get rid of having http request as arguments in action, and let Spring automatically get the content in a var... (thanks for your reply anyway)

Answer (score 109, accepted):

Best way I found until now is:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/greeting", method = POST, consumes = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public String greetingJson(HttpEntity<String> httpEntity) {
    String json = httpEntity.getBody();
    // json contains the plain json string
```

Let me know if there are other alternatives.

Comment: I had to add `@RequestBody` before `HttpEntity<String> httpEntity` to make this work. Hope this helps.

Comment: Neither way worked for me, sadly, with my custom `HttpMessageConverter`-s.

Comment: I had the same issue like you, but I now solved it.
Instead of overriding the configureMessageConverters,
override the: extendMessageConverters
Now you can use @RequestBody String body

Comment: you can directly annotate with @RequestBody
ex - public ResponseEntity request(@RequestBody String json) {...}

Answer (score 37):

You can just use

`@RequestBody String pBody`

Comment: This doesn't work for me.  I've receiving a URL-encoded form data string containing both the URL query parameters and the POST data, not a raw JSON copy of the data as required.

Comment: Are you using application/json as content-type??

Comment: Yes.  Checked the request via chrome's inspector and all the headers look good, including content-type.  But Spring is URL-encoding it, appending it to the URL-encoded query string, and giving me that. @davidcassidy's approach above, however, works fine.

Answer (score 26):

Only `HttpServletRequest` worked for me. `HttpEntity` gave `null` string.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;

@RequestMapping(value = "/greeting", method = POST, consumes = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public String greetingJson(HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {
    final String json = IOUtils.toString(request.getInputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    System.out.println("json = " + json);
    return "Hello World!";
}
```

Comment: String payload = IOUtils.toString(request.getInputStream(), Charset.forName("UTF8"));

Comment: Same here, only this answer works. I'm on Spring Boot 2.2.1.RELEASE, so perhaps the behaviour has changed since the original post.

Comment: I get error: The method toString() in the type Object is not applicable for the arguments (ServletInputStream, Charset)

Comment: We will get an issue when we parse JSON with Long data type characters, the spring will return 404

Answer (score 8):

simplest way that works for me is

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/greeting", method = POST, consumes = MediaType.ALL_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public String greetingJson(String raw) {
    System.out.println("json = " + raw);
    return "OK";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have dozens of Methods that need to get HTTP body as JSON and convert it to custom data type, it is a better way to implement the support on the framework

```
public static class Data {
    private String foo;
    private String bar;
}

//convert http body to Data object.
//you can also use String parameter type to get the raw json text.
@RequestMapping(value = "/greeting")
@ResponseBody
public String greetingJson(@JsonBody Data data) {
    System.out.println(data);
    return "OK";
}
```

notice that we using user defined annotation `@JsonBody`.

```
// define custom annotation
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.PARAMETER)
public @interface JsonBody {
    String encoding() default "utf-8";
}

//annotation processor for JsonBody 
@Slf4j
public class JsonBodyArgumentResolver implements HandlerMethodArgumentResolver {

    @Override
    public boolean supportsParameter(MethodParameter parameter) {
        return parameter.getParameterAnnotation(JsonBody.class) != null;
    }

    @Override
    public Object resolveArgument(MethodParameter parameter, ModelAndViewContainer mavContainer, NativeWebRequest webRequest,
                              WebDataBinderFactory binderFactory) throws Exception {
        JsonBody annotation = parameter.getParameterAnnotation(JsonBody.class);
        assert annotation != null;
        ServletRequest servletRequest = webRequest.getNativeRequest(ServletRequest.class);
        if (servletRequest == null) {
            throw new Exception("can not get ServletRequest from NativeWebRequest");
        }
        String copy = StreamUtils.copyToString(servletRequest.getInputStream(), Charset.forName(annotation.encoding()));
        return new Gson().fromJson(copy, parameter.getGenericParameterType());
    }
}

// register the annotation processor
@Component
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addArgumentResolvers(List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> resolvers) {
        resolvers.add(new JsonBodyArgumentResolver());
    }
}
```

Comment: it's too much complicated, just need to receive it by HttpServletRequest, HttpEntity or pure String with @RequestBody annotation

Answer (score 3):

As of 4.1 you can now use `RequestEntity<String> requestEntity` and access the body by `requestEntity.getBody()`

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/RequestEntity.html