# Access RequestBody of REST endpoint in spring

Tags: java, spring, rest

I want to access the request body object of my REST endpoint, which is already deserialized.

My REST controller looks like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "car/{id}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public ResponseEntity updateCar(@RequestBody Car car, @PathVariable("id") String carId) {
    // My update logic, how i update the car object in database
    // with the retrieved request body. 
    // Here i want to access the raw request body e.g. the JSON string
}
```

**Edit:**

The Car POJO:

```
public class Car {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String color;
    private List<String> additions =  new ArrayList<>();

    // setters and getters
}
```

When i want to make a partial update, e.g a PUT request like this:

```
curl -X PUT \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -d "{ \"color\" : \"Green\" }" \
    http://localhost:8080/car/1234
```

After the deserialization of the request body above, the `additions` field is an empty list although i didn't specified it. If i could access the raw json request body, then i can check whether the `additions` field is specified or not.

Is it possible to access the raw request body after it was deserialized?

Comment: Not sure about your use case but why do you want to do that?

Comment: @RishikeshDhokare check my question, i updated it.

Comment: Ofcourse it is empty, that is what you initialize it with.

Comment: @Oni1, I dont think this is a good idea to access the raw request body. I guess you can omit your list initialization, so it would be `null` if `additions` parametr wasn't specified.

Comment: Yes.... But in the JSON request body, i don't specify it. I want to make it possible to update partially.. Therefore i want to check e.g. if the `additions` field is really specified as an empty list in the request or is it the default value?

Comment: @Leffchik You're right, but atm it is not possible to change the model classes.

Comment: @Oni1, weird, but in that case I guess any solution would be hacky. You can get request json as string then in a first place ([like that for ex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17891906/2653420)) and then deserialize it manually the way you want.

Comment: @Leffchik That's really hacky.. I wish there is nice solution from spring..

Comment: have you tried @JsonDeserialize (from jackson) and create your own deserializer? That's where you can check if things are not as they should be