# Spring post not working -- my json is sent from frontend i can see it in logs but my backend gets Null

Tags: jquery, spring

So basically i checked other questions and the most answers are to use `@RequestBody` in my Post method on backend but it still throws 500 error with all my received json data is `null`

Any other suggestions what can be the problem?

here's my Rest:

```
@PostMapping({ "/createScreen" })
    public ResponseEntity<String> createScreen(@RequestBody AdminWrapper adminWrapper) {
        System.out.println(adminWrapper);
        adminDao.saveAll(adminWrapper.getAdminList());

        return new ResponseEntity<String>(HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

and this is the json i want to send back:

```
{
    "module": "testModule",
        "networkId": 1,
            "adminInfos":
    [{
        "id": 1,
        "key": "Test",
        "value": "TestValue",
        "defValue": "TestDef",
        "type": "checkbox",
        "isActive": true
    }]
}
```

but in the log i see this:

```
adminWrapper [module=null, networkId = null, adminInfos = null ]
```

Request from frontend:

```
function submit() {

let adminWrapper = {
        module: 'testModule',
        networkId: 1,
        adminInfos: []
    }

$('#content  > .form-group').each(function () {

        let value = $(this).find('input').val();
        if ($(this).find('input').attr('type') === 'checkbox')

            value = $(this).find('input').prop('checked')

        let adminInfo = {

            id: $(this).find('input').attr('data-id'),
            key: $(this).find('input').attr('data-key'),
            value: value
        }
        adminWrapper.adminInfos.push(adminInfo);
    })

$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/.../createScreen',
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: JSON.stringify({
            adminWrapper
        })
    })
}
```

Comment: Have you set the content type header to application/json in your POST request?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49010773/4364101 you can try this to see exactly what String body is arriving at the controller too if it helps with debugging

Comment: Also, do you have a 1. no args constructor for AdminWrapper 2. getters+setters for all fields? You'll need to have the same for any other class fields like your NetworkId

Comment: yes i got my content type right, got constructor and getters setters aswell, checked if i typed something wrong but everything looks good

Comment: Good stuff Kerk, just for a sanity check can you add how you're making the request too? :) If you're sending from Chrome, you can use the dev tools, view the network tab, and see what you're sending there too

Comment: i edited my question and added the request

Comment: `JSON.stringify({adminWrapper})` is wrapping your object in an extra layer I think, try remove those curly brackets. You can confirm this by checking the network tab in chrome too. Another tool you can use for a sanity check is Postman where you can fill in the raw JSON you would be expecting to send

Comment: removed the brackets still same and in postman i get status 200 so my request works but the values are somehow null..

Comment: just to make sure I understand: when you make the request through postman, do you receive the values you expect filled in in Spring? And in a separate test, can you see what the request body is when the request is being sent from your browser?

Comment: in browser in the requestbody i see what i want so everything is sent fine from frontend but in backend all the sent values are null like if i would send empty json to backend, and if i send the with postman it works i see the values in my database

Comment: what exactly is being sent by the frontend though, just to be sure. If it works with postman that would really suggest its the client doing something wrong, so I'd focus there.

Comment: yes good point i checked again what is sent from frontend and i realize that one of the values were missing from the json that was sent and now it works finally, thanks for all the tips appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem is in my

```
        let adminInfo = {
            id: $(this).find('input').attr('data-id'),
            key: $(this).find('input').attr('data-key'),
            value: value
        }
```

i forgot to add these:

```
        "defValue": "TestDef",
        "type": "checkbox",
        "isActive": true
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your AdminWrapper.java is not matching the structure with request josn which is coming from front end, try to match each and every field from request json.

- you can refer below example

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-request-response-body