# How to get raw JSON body in Spring REST controller?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

The API below accept a json string from client, and the map it into a Email object. How can I get request body (`email`) as a raw String? (I want both raw-string and typed version of `email` parameter)

PS: This question is NOT a duplicate of: [How to access plain json body in Spring rest controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17866996/how-to-access-plain-json-body-in-spring-rest-controller)

```
@PostMapping(value = "/mailsender")
public ResponseEntity<Void> sendMail(@RequestBody Email email) {
    //...
    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Comment: have you tried using the toString or StringBuilder method?

Comment: Why, _exactly_, is it not a duplicate?

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- The other question is about getting ONLY a raw String, not caring about typed (mapped) version of the parameter

Comment: @kalpajagrawalla I think it will cause some overhead, since we have to convert the object back to a JSON String

Comment: And did you try just putting both?

Comment: Just put both a `String` and typed object in there with `@RequestBody`. What you duped as not a duplicate is actually a duplicate as that is the way to obtain the raw payload. However, I would suggest that if you need both, you are doing something wrong with your typed object.

Comment: This is neither a duplicate (the specific requirement is to get both the parsed model and the raw HTTP body), nor it is a dubious use case.I can give you a concrete example where this would be highly useful: I want to use Bean Validation on the parsed model, and I need to pass on the raw body (JSON) to another downstream consumer, e.g. an Azure Event Hub, the Java library for which accepts (among others) a raw string (JSON) as input.

Comment: By the way, when trying to passing both `@RequestBody Model` and `HttpEntity<String>` as arguments, depending on the order of the arguments either the body of the `HttpEntity` is `null` or the model gets parsed as if there was no body. I guess that is because the InputStream gets consumed only once and is therefore not available for the other argument.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it in more than one way, listing two

```
 1. **Taking string as the paramater**,
     @PostMapping(value = "/mailsender")
        public ResponseEntity<Void> sendMail(@RequestBody String email) {
            //... the email is the string can be converted to Json using new JSONObject(email) or using jackson.
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
        }

 2. **Using Jackson** 
         @PostMapping(value = "/mailsender")
            public ResponseEntity<Void> sendMail(@RequestBody Email email) {
                //...
                ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(); 
                String email = mapper.writeValueAsString(email); //this is in string now
                return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
            }
```

Comment: The first way is the solution I'm using right now, but I wish Spring provide a better way to solve this problem.

Comment: the first one: email is a encoded form string,  which is modified by spring

Answer (score 0):

Spring uses Jackson for this in the back, you could use it to serialize it to an string. Like so:

```
@Autowired private ObjectMapper jacksonMapper;

@PostMapping(value = "/mailsender")
public ResponseEntity<Void> sendMail(@RequestBody Email email) {
    //...
    log.info("Object as String: " + jacksonMapper.writeValueAsString(email));
    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not get all things about this question, but I try to answer as I understand. Well,
if you want to get request body:

- as you say [How to access plain json body in Spring rest controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17866996/how-to-access-plain-json-body-in-spring-rest-controller) here already writen how to do this. If something wrong, maybe you send wrong json or not suitable type as you wite inside `Email` class. Maybe your request comes url filter
- second way try like this:

  ```
  private final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

  @PostMapping(value = "/mailsender")
  public ResponseEntity<Void> sendMail(HttpServletRequest req) {
      // read request body
      InputStream body = req.getInputStream();        
      byte[] result = ByteStreams.toByteArray(body);
      String text =new String(result,"UTF-8");
      //convert to object
      Email email = mapper.readValue(body, Email .class);
      return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
  }
  ```

If you want to convert object to json string [read this post](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/convert-java-object-to-json-string-using-jackson-api/)

Answer (score -1):

**you can create `json` of type string using GSON library**

```java
Gson gson = new Gson();

@PostMapping(value = "/endpoint")
public ResponseEntity<Void> actionController(@RequestBody Car car) {
    //...
    log.info("Object as String: " + this.gson.toJson(car));
    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
}
```