# Spring 5 Controller for Stripe Webhook Endpoint

Tags: json, spring, stripe-payments

I know I am not the first one to ask this question, and I could post several links on StackOverflow where this question was asked, but I haven't seen where my problem is specifically addressed.

So, I have a Spring 5 Framework RESTful Controller setup, this is not Spring Boot.

```
@PostMapping(value = "/webhook-endpoint")
public HttpStatus stripeWebhookEndpoint(
        @RequestBody String stripeJsonEvent, 
        @RequestHeader("Stripe-Signature") String sigHeader)
{
    System.out.println("stripeWebhookEndpoint: START: json = " + stripeJsonEvent);
    return HttpStatus.OK;
}
```

Judging by the other examples I have seen, this absolutely should work.   But in my case, I am getting an HTTP 400 Error as follows:

```
[http-nio-8080-exec-7] WARN org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver - 
Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: 
JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.lang.String` out of START_OBJECT token; 
nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: 
Cannot deserialize instance of `java.lang.String` out of START_OBJECT token
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 1]]
```

I have even tried adding:  consumes = "text/plain; application/json" and I get the same error.
If I can get just get the JSON, then I'll be fine after that.  There will be plenty of examples to parse this Stripe event.

What did work was when I had this configuration:
@RequestBody Object stripeJsonEvent
And then I could see the Json as part of the object, but then I couldn't cast from the Object to String.

I think what is important to add here is that I am using the Stripe CLI to create this call to my controller.   With Stripe CLI the first thing I did was create the listener:
stripe listen --forward-to localhost:8080/myapp/api/stripe/webhook-endpoint

In another Terminal window I did:  stripe trigger payment_method.attached

So, this is the error I have.  I'm going to try from another REST client like PostMan and see if I get the same results.
I'll keep playing with it and see if I can come up with another fix.

Thanks!

Comment: Might be a duplication of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17866996/how-to-access-plain-json-body-in-spring-rest-controller

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access plain json body in Spring rest controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17866996/how-to-access-plain-json-body-in-spring-rest-controller)