# How to get plain body string and object mapping in Spring Boot @PostMapping

Tags: spring-boot

Giving the following code:

```java
    @PostMapping(value = "/wc-order")
    public void getWcOrder(@RequestBody Order order, @RequestHeader Map<String, String> headers, @RequestBody String plainJsonBody){
        String webhookSignature = headers.get("x-wc-webhook-signature");
        String hashedBody = doHMAC(plainJsonBody);
        if (hashedBody.equals(webhookSignature)) {
            // all good
        }
    }
```

The JSON body will successfully be mapped to the Order object.

Furthermore I would like to have the JSON body as well as a string to finally hash it and compare with the signature. Unfortunately I don't know how to extract plain body without loosing the capability to map it to order Object.

Is there a simple way to achieve it?

I've tried as in [How to access plain json body in Spring rest controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17866996/how-to-access-plain-json-body-in-spring-rest-controller)

But here I loose the capability of the deserialization to the Order object.

Comment: You do not lose capability to deserialize the post body contents into Order object if you read the contents as a string only. You can use `new JsonMapper().readValue(rawJsonString, Order.class)` or similar construct to do same as `@PostMapping` does for the object by default. The return value is Order object filled with values from the JSON string - or an exception in case deserialization fails.

Answer (score 1):

you cant use two `RequestBody` inside the same Request, you have three options to throw with your scenario

1- the first one merge `plainJsonBody` inside order as a variable and set @NotBalnk on it.

2- you can change  `plainJsonBody` to `@RequestParam` and set the param as a `reuired=true`

3- you can replace all `@RequestBody` to @RequestPart`

Comment: There is also option 4 - opt to read request body as a string only and deserialize it in code throwing a `HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST` if that fails.